# Running dlib on Qt c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, qt-creator, dlib

I'm trying to add dlib library to Qt project to run fhog_object_detector_ex.cpp file on ubuntu. I've built dlib using CMake and now i'm trying to run it in Qt.I have added these lines in myproject.pro

```
SOURCES += $$PWD/dlib-19.2/dlib/all/source.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/dlib-19.2

LIBS += $$PWD/dlib19.2/examples/build/dlib_build/libdlib.a
LIBS += -pthread
```

I am including these headers in code:

```
#include <dlib/svm_threaded.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/data_io.h>
```

but when i run the program i got errors, here are some errors:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qad4r.png)

Please help me to deal with it.

Comment: May I ask what's inside `source.cpp`? It seems that it's the cause of all undefined references. Also why not use `cmake` which supports `Qt` out of the box so there is no need to switch to `qmake`? (if you use Qt Creator as your IDE, native support for `cmake` is present there too)

Comment: In [source.cpp] there are some include headers to refer to the paths of the files needed for dlib.

Comment: I'm not using cmake because i don't have great experience with it. i have just run the dlib files as the description for it said. @rbaleksandar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to X11 in addition to pthread.

Comment: Thanks it worked but an error appeared in the include lines #include <dlib/svm_threaded.h> so i added the whole path, is it ok?. At first after running the code it gave me an exception that it can't load a png photo so i added these lines to the .pro file `LIBS += -lpng -ljpeg
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` but it still giving me errors.

Comment: @LilyBaker  DavisKing, How did you link X11?
I am new to QT.

Comment: -lX11. So just like linking to anything else.

Comment: @DavisKing Just including that still gave me the error and when I included `PKGCONFIG += x11` and included a line `dlib::frontal_face_detector detector = dlib::get_frontal_face_detector();` in the code then it gave me the error `:-1: error: x11 development package not found`

I have posted a question regarding this, can you please have a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671972/how-to-link-x11-to-qt-pro-file

Comment: Capitol X. Look carefully